# Cannot find unzipped files from WinZip Android app

Tags: zip

I have installed [WinZip for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.winzip.android) and unzipped a file. However, I cannot find the extracted files anywhere on my SD card. I always have to open the WinZip app and go to the last zip option to view all the files.

Is there any option to view the unzipped files on my SD card or to select the path/folder before extraction?

Answer (score 1):

The [app's description on the playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.winzip.android) does not speak of "unzipping files to your sdcard". It rather seems to simply "handle" them, only temporarily extracting files to process them. Which would explain why you cannot find the files anywhere outside the zip-file itself (or outside that app).

If you want to extract files to handle them separately, you might rather wish to take a look at e.g. [AndroZip Dateimanager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agilesoftresource) instead, which is explicitly stating to extract files:

> AndroZip File Manager helps you copy, delete, move, unzip/unpack, compress, encrypted ZIP supported, search, and organize your files, music, pictures, and folders just like you would do on your PC.

Comment: Thanks a lot Izzy.. Gave me a clear insight.. Will install these apps !